# WLAN0 stopped working

Tags: pi-2, dhcp, wifi

For some reason, my WIFI dongle doesn't want to connect to the internet anymore.  It was not too long ago.  But I think something happened that caused it not to work.  I can't figure out what's going wrong but I think it has something to do with me uninstalling the `dhcpcd5` package.

I have a strong feeling that removing that package somehow messed up my WIFI connection.  It was working perfectly before that.  If anybody knows what to do about this, that'd be great.

I even tried to connect to my pi through an ethernet connection but I still have no luck with it.  I can't even scan it on my network.

I know for a fact that the WIFI was configured correctly because everything seemed to work fine until not too long ago.  I have absolutely no clue what I did.  Let me know if you need anymore information than this.

Thanks for any help.  It's appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of ifconfig? What is the output off lsusb? Have you tried reinstalling dhcpd5?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Everything's fine.  I need to reinstall dhcpd5 but I can't figure out how to do it without a network connection.

Comment: First everything is not fine or you would not have asked a question? The things I asked for will help us diagnose the problem something you admitted several times in your question that you don't know. To install a package (assuming you are using Raspbian) do the following sudo apt-get install dhacpd5.

Comment: This is one of these 'I cut my hand off with a chainsaw and now it doesn't work' questions.

WHY did you delete your network management software????

Do you have a backup?

We MAY be able to suggest a fix if you list the contents of your `/etc/network/interfaces`  and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` files.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Sorry, I meant everything was fine with the Wifi adapter.  That's what you wanted me to check with lsusb right?  The thing is, I can't do sudo apt-get install dhcpcd5 because I don't have a network connection.

Comment: @Milliways I do, I just wanted to know if there was a better way.  Offline package installation maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've fixed it by restoring from another backup I had.  I don't even know if I should keep this question up.  But just in case there are people out there who are as clueless as I am.

**DO NOT DELETE THE `dhcpcd5` PACKAGE EVER**

Never thought I'd be saying that.  Nobody in their right mind would delete their network management software, right?  I learned the hard way.  Took a lot of work getting the computer back to normal.

Fortunately, there is a much better solution for other people that may run into this problem.

Here's how you can install the package without a connection.

1. Download the `dhcpcd5` package [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/armhf/dhcpcd5/download).
2. Move the .deb package onto a usb drive.
3. Plug that drive into one of the PI's  usb slots.
4. To mount the drive, use this command `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /path/to/mount/folder`.  sda number will vary.
5. Move the .deb file into your home folder.
6. To install the package use the command `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file` followed by the command `sudo apt-get install -f`.
7. Restart the Pi.  Hopefully, your internet connection will be working once again.  If it doesn't work, there may be another problem.

If anyone needs more information on how to get this done.  Leave a comment and I'll try to get back to you.